# How can I read the json data from json file in google map api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I am  trying to make a  google map api with markers, which  will show the latitude and longitude of some places.I am trying to do this with json file but it is not working..
here is my code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Cluster Map</title>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var markers = [];

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(43.474144,-112.03866);
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 7,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            markMultiple();
        }

        function markMap(latLng, content){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            markers.push(marker);
        }
        function markMultiple(){
            $.parseJSON('test.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data.markers, function(i, obj) {
                    var latLng =  new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat,obj.lng);
                    var content = obj.id + ':' + obj.lat + ',' + obj.lng;

                    markMap(latLng, content);
                });
            });


             var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        }



        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-container">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

please help me..

Comment: Instead of `$.parseJSON`, probably you need `$.getJSON` method.

Comment: Is this code correct I mean I used $getJSON also.. but it didn't  work. Any other way You know???

Comment: What output do you get from test.json in browser

Answer (score 0):

Engineer was right, you need to use $.getJSON method, $.parseJSON takes a JSON string, it doesn't load an external file.

getJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ 
parseJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

I put your code in a jsFiddle and it is working with getJSON and an alternative test JSON file (you didn't provide the original test.json you're using).

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data.markers, function(i, obj) {
                    var latLng =  new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat,obj.lng);
                    var content = obj.id + ':' + obj.lat + ',' + obj.lng;

                    markMap(latLng, content);
                });
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WYfjv/

If your code is not working maybe your JSON is not well formatted (try JSONLINT to test it). Also, if you are already improving, I would advise to use a normal for loop rather than $.each  :)